# Как отправить форму с сайта в телеграм через python скрипт

Tags: python, telebot

Столкнулся с такой задачей: есть форма на `HTML`:

```
<form action="form.py">
            <h3>форма</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="имя" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'имя'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'имя') this.value = '' "/><br>
            <input type="text" name="fname"value="фамилия" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'фамилия'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'фамилия') this.value = '' "/><br>
            <textarea name="msg" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'отчество'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'отчество') this.value=''">отчество</textarea>
            <p class="send">
                <input type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ"  />
```

Нужно что бы после ввода в эту форму данные отправлялись в телеграм бот.

Помогите пожалуйста с решением!

Вот что я написал в `form.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import request
import cgi

our_form = cgi.FieldStorage()
token = '19:AAF'

uname = our_form.getfirst('uname', 'не задано')
conta = our_form.getfirst('conta', 'не задано')
msg = our_form.getfirst('msg', 'не задано')

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(uname, conta, msg)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать связку вашим WEB сервером с Python

Есть например такие фреймворки для связки, как [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com)

Пример реализации вашего кода на фреймворке Flask

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

def sendMessage(name, surname, secondName):
    #Ваш код на Python для отправления сообщений в Telegram через бота
    pass

@app.route('/')
def mainPage():
    html = """<form method="POST">
            <h3>форма</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="имя" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'имя'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'имя') this.value = '' "/><br>
            <input type="text" name="fname"value="фамилия" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'фамилия'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'фамилия') this.value = '' "/><br>
            <textarea name="msg" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'отчество'" onfocus="if(this.value == 'отчество') this.value=''">отчество</textarea>
            <p class="send">
                <input type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ"/>"""
    return html

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getData():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('name') #имя
        surname = request.form.get('fname') #фамилия
        secondName = request.form.get('msg') #отчество
        sendMessage(name, surname, secondName)
        return 'Данные отправлены'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста пример для реализации на django